# How to set date popup to below text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am creating date field in angular 4, In that when I click on the date field Date popup must come below the date field.

Here is my code

```
 <div class="col-3">
  <div class="form-group calenderForm calenderForm1">
   <label for="templateName">REPAIR DATE (FROM)</label>
     <owl-date-time name="repairDateFrom"
       [(ngModel)]="repairDateFrom" 
       [max]="max"
       [type]="'calendar'"
       [dateFormat]="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
       [placeHolder]="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
       ></owl-date-time>
       <div class="error-message-block"></div>
     <input type="hidden" name="repairDateFrom" id = "repairDateFrom" 
     value="{{repairDateFrom | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" 
    (click)="closeDatePopUp()"/>
   </div>
  </div>
```

whether I have to use ngModel function or I have to write in picker plugin component to achieve the result.
Please help me that how can I achieve it.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The best and easy idea is to install **[ng2-popover](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-popover)** . Popover is for angular  applications using bootstrap but if you don't want to use it without bootstrap - just simply create your own css class. Popover doesn't depend of jquery.

If you are useing bootstrap 4 powered for Angular you can implement popovers out of the box. [Quick and easy popovers](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples)

```
<input type="input"  placement="bottom"
        ngbPopover="Popover text." popoverTitle="Popover on bottom">
```

[image]